# What is the fastest method for factoring this

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics

I want the square root of $.09e^{-2t} + .24e^{-t} +.34 +.24e^t + .09e^{2t}$  I need this to find the moment generating function given it's product with itself (the product of two identical moment generating functions)

Comment: Are the coefficients exact, or are they your numerical approximations to given exact expressions?

Comment: The exact answer should be .3e^-t + .4 + .3e^t according to the actuarial exam p solutions manual problem 137 http://www.math.binghamton.edu/actuary/1-sample-sol.pdf

Comment: The square of this begins with $0.09e^{-2t}$. You wrote $0.9e^{-2t}$. The expression you wrote does not have a nice square root.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: For the revised version, it is clear that if there is a nice square root it will have shape $0.3e^{-t}+c+0.3e^{t}$. Looking at the term $.24e^{-t}$, we see that $c$ has to be $0.4$. Now we square to see whether this gives us the right constant term $0.34$. The constant term of the square is $c^2+2(0.09)$, which does turn out to be $0.34$ if we pick $c=0.4$.

Answer (score 1):

Given the symmetry, you should define $y=x+\frac 1x$.  Then this becomes $0.9y^2+.24y-1.46$ and you are guaranteed $|y| \ge 2$  I don't see a nice square root, but you can factor it using completion of the square or the quadratic formula if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have an equation of the form:

$\begin{align}
y &= .09e^{−2t}+.24e^{−t}+.34+.24e^{t}+.09e^{2t} \\
z &= .09+.24x+.34x^2+.24x^3+.09x^4 \\
\frac {100} 9 z &= 1 + \frac 8 3 x + \frac {34} 9 x^2 + \frac 8 3 x^3 + x^4 
\end{align}$

Check binomial expansion:
$(x + b)^4 = x^4 + 4bx^3 + 6b^2x^2 + 4b^3x + b^4$

$\begin{align}
4b &= \frac 8 3 \\
6b^2 &= \frac {34} 9 \\
4b^3 &= \frac 8 3 \\
b^4 &= 1
\end{align}$

Nothing satisfies this so check trinomial expansion:
$(x^2 + bx + c)^2 = x^4 + 2bx^3 + (2c+b^2)x^2 + 2bcx + c^2$

$\begin{align}
2b &= \frac 8 3 \\
2c + b^2 &= \frac {34} 9 \\
2bc &= \frac 8 3 \\
c^2 &= 1
\end{align}$

This is satisfied by $c = 1$ and $b = \frac 4 3$.
$$\frac {100} 9 z = \left(x^2 + \frac 4 3 x + 1\right)^2$$
$$\sqrt{y} = \pm \frac 3 {10} \left(e^{t} + \frac 4 3  + e^{-t}\right)$$

---

P.S. The fastest way to factor something is to use a computer.